# Support needed for web scraping to Tableau

Tags: html, screen-scraping

Theres a site which is daily updating. I need to get it directly to tableau and it need to refresh automatically. I have tried google sheets but it gives me an error saying please try again. No luck at all. Is there any way to upload the table in the below link to tableau which is refreshing daily?
Its only showing 25 rows. I need to get all the rows there.

https://www.cse.lk/pages/trade-summary/trade-summary.component.html

Can you anyone please help ?

Comment: Yes, by writing a web scraper.  You could also try making use of that download link.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks. can you please tell me how to write a one?

Comment: That topic could fill the better part of a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find the link for the api of the particular site. Do a python web scraping using requests and you can do the task easily